# How to Add and Remove Information in a form using Jquery when a checkbox is checked and unchecked?

Tags: jquery

if (selection == 'Yes') {
$('.form-item').show();

and

if (selection == 'No') {
$('.form-item').hide();

Comment: The check box for "yes" works perfectly, but when the "no" box is checked the entire form disappears.

Comment: Is the code not working or ? Please include more relevant code.

Comment: The first part is working.  When I check the "no" box it removes the entire form instead of the information that was added.

Comment: <script>
 $('#checkbox-731a364b-ad8f-4d92-b3a7-c3fe55fddcae input').click(function() {
     selection = $(this).val();
       
     if (selection == 'Yes') {
         $('.form-item').show();
      }
      else      
        if (selection == 'No') {
              $('.form-item').hide();
            }
    });
</script>

Comment: Please include the relevant html